# Creating a notiftication when function is initiated in a Shiny Application

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following R Shiny Application:

```
library(shiny)


shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
      title = "Tweetminer",
      titleWidth = 350
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(
      width = 350,
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Menu Item")
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      fluidRow(
        tabBox(
          tabPanel("Select tweets",
                   numericInput("tweet_amount", "Amount of tweets:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
                   div(style="display:inline-block",numericInput("tweet_long", "Longitude:", 10, min = 1, max = 100)),
                   div(style="display:inline-block",numericInput("tweet_lat", "Latitude:", 10, min = 1, max = 100)),
                   #selectInput("tweet_name", "Account name", choices = c("@realDonaldTrump","@GorgeNails"), width = NULL, placeholder = NULL),
                   selectInput("tweet_name", "Account name", choices = c("@realDonaldTrump","@Yankees"), selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE,
                               selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL),
                   actionButton("get_tweets", "Fetch the tweets"),
                   hidden(
                     div(id='text_div',
                         verbatimTextOutput("text")
                     )
                   )
                  )
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

  test_list <- c(1,2,3)
  run_function <- reactive({
    for(i in test_list){
      Sys.sleep(2)
    }
  })


  observeEvent(input$get_tweets, {
    run_function()
    toggle('text_div')
    output$text <- renderText({"You're now connecting to the API"})
  })
  }
)
```

This application should allow users to input parameters after which tweets will be scraped. However - because it will take some time Im looking for a way to inform users this will take a while.

Using this function:

```
 observeEvent(input$get_tweets, {
    run_function()
    toggle('text_div')
    output$text <- renderText({"You're now connecting to the API"})
  })
```

I inform the user that the function (run_function() in this example, a mockup but just for reproducing purposes) is ready. However Im looking for a notice after you initiate the function and when its done.

So after you press the first time it should say something like - function initiated and after the function is ready -> "You .. api".

Any thoughts on what I should change to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

You can use withProgress function, check this example:

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
    withProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress', detail = 'This may take a while...', value = 0, {
      for (i in 1:15) {
        incProgress(1/15)
        Sys.sleep(0.25)
      }
    })
    plot(cars)
  })
```

[More info](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.2/withProgress.html)

[image]

**EDIT: New example:**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton(inputId = 'DoSomething', label = 'Do something'),
    verbatimTextOutput('t1')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$t1 <- renderPrint('Doing nothing...')

    run_function <- reactive({

        withProgress(message = "Starting...", max = 60, value = 0, {

            for (i in 1:25) {
                incProgress(1)
                Sys.sleep(0.25)
            }

            setProgress(message = "Connected..")

            for (i in 1:25) {
                incProgress(1)
                Sys.sleep(0.25)
            }

            setProgress(message = "Doing Stuffs...")

            for (i in 1:10) {
                incProgress(1)
                Sys.sleep(0.25)
            }

            setProgress(message = "Disconecting...")
        })

        return('Finish')
    })

    observeEvent(input$DoSomething, {

        output$t1 <- renderPrint(run_function())

    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thanks for your input. However, it's not clear to me yet how you would use this in a reactive context. Could you elaborate on how I want to do this is if I want a progress bar and status update afterwards? So a combination or your and my answer.

Comment: Check my edit.. A new example using withProgress inside a reactive function.. ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort